# How to paginate posts correctly that belong to a particular category and are random ordered

Tags: query-posts

I was interested to read the answer to this question on how to paginate posts correctly that are random ordered.
[Is it possible to paginate posts correctly that are random ordered?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-it-possible-to-paginate-posts-correctly-that-are-random-ordered)

My goal is to randomly order posts that appear in a certain category on my site, in this case artists. Here is the code for the loop. In my case I use the wp_pagenavi plugin

```
       <div class="news-posts">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts('cat=6&orderby=rand&posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=. $paged);?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <?php //include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
     <div class="entry">
         <?php
        global $more; $more = 0;
        the_post_thumbnail('medium');
        the_content("Continue Reading",FALSE); 
         ?>
      </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php //include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I used the filter to modify the ORDER BY statement of WP_query from the link above

```
session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

$seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
if (empty($seed)) {
  $seed = rand();
  $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
}

$orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
return $orderby_statement;
}
```

and this works fine when the artists page is viewed. As explained a random number is generated on the first page load then this is stored in a SESSION variable and used as the $seed for further paginated requests. This ensures that any potential for repeated artists posts is eliminated and a fresh set of artists posts is returned when the user clicks on page 2 or 3 of the pagination

However posts in different categories including events and news also get treated randomly which isn't  what is desired.

I'd like these to be the latest first. I tried adding orderly = DESC but this makes no difference to that loop. The function from the previous post appears to override it. Is there a method of targeting just the artist category to be random within the seed function and to leave other loops alone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `add_filter` line inside the template itself & no filter in the "functions.php" file. Then just after retrieving the posts remove that filter with a call to `remove_filter`. The actual function may still reside in the functions.php file

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
// get all the posts for this specific loop here
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
```

This ensures that no other loop gets affected from this filter

In case you want to use another way, you can  change the filter to accept 2 parameters, the 2nd parameter here is the concerned WP_Query object. In that object, you can examine the query parameters to determine weather to apply the filter or not

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby', 10, 2);
function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement, $query) {
    if($query->get('cat') != 6)
        return $orderby_statement;
    // apply the random seed here
}
```

Comment: Or use `remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );` as the first line in the callback.