# Using $seed on a custom post type for randomly displayed posts

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, pre-get-posts

I saw this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-it-possible-to-paginate-posts-correctly-that-are-random-ordered) to display posts randomly without duplicating them. However how do you apply this to a custom post type?

Below is what I'm using in functions to make it randomly display.

```
    session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to paginate posts correctly that are random ordered?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-it-possible-to-paginate-posts-correctly-that-are-random-ordered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it should work. Add the filter in `pre_get_posts` if it's your post type archive, otherwise remove it for any queries that follow the post type archive main query.

```
function wpd_add_posts_orderby( $query ){
    if( $query->is_post_type_archive('your-cpt') ){
        add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
    } else {
        remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_add_posts_orderby' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it brought up this error on my page when I added this to my functions:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'edit_posts_orderby' not found or invalid function name .

Comment: does your `edit_posts_orderby` function exist? this isn't a replacement for your code, it just conditionally hooks the function you have in your example.