# Random post order into Category Pages

Tags: categories

I have a Worpdress Blog and I would like to display post randomly into all the category pages.

For example, when I go here http://www.iltrentinodeibambini.it/category/rubriche/lo-sai-che/ I want to see the post randomly ordered, not sorted by date.

I've tried to find a Plugin that could help me, but I didn't find anything. How can I do? Is there any PHP code that I can put before the loop in my "page.php" file?

I'm using Throne Theme with WP 4.0 (http://themeforest.net/item/throne-personal-blogmagazine-wordpress-theme/8134834).

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: randomizing the order is fairly simple via the `pre_get_posts` hook, however, the task is complicated by the fact that this alone will give you truly random order, meaning you could see posts repeated on subsequent pages. to solve this you need to seed the randomization, like in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/33275/4771).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following line of code in your category.php file for Random posts.

```
<ul>
 <?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=5'); 
    foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php  the_title(); ?></a>
     </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Won't work. This will break what your category page is all about. Custom queries don't solve problems, they create more problems